# CR-10 Max slight shock when touching heat bed or frams

Tags: creality-cr-10, grounding

I just got my new CR-10 Max and got it assembled. I turned it on, was auto-leveling it, and I received a slight shock from the leveling bed and the frame. Is this a grounding issue? I haven't even printed anything yet and this happens. Anyone have any tips or heard this happening before? I've sent 3 emails to Creality already and gotten no response.

Comment: It's probably a harmless thing related to the noise filtering in the power supply. You can fix the issue by grounding the printer. It's been [discussed before](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/electric-shock-from-ender-3-printer-psu) on this site.

Comment: If the above link doesn't help, are you sure its not your bodies ESD to ground.